# Some quick yes/no questions regarding Solana transaction validation process

Tags: transactions, solana-program, validator, runtime

### What My End Game Is

I'm trying to understand what the fastest way to execute a transaction on the Solana chain is. From reading the Solana docs, I have some guesses, but need confirmation from anyone :)

---

Few background questions:

- It is my understanding that every epoch, a particular validator or "slot leader" is chosen to validate all sent transactions, correct?
- If I want to guarantee my transaction is the first to get in when reacting to new information, I would want to be connected to *that* validator, correct?

Looking at [the solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/validator/runtime) we get the image below:
[image]

This leads to the following questions as well:

- Can a validator **cannot** be both in TVU mode and TPU mode? Seems like no, otherwise they can write and validate whatever...
- If the answer last question is as I suspect **no**, then in order to guarantee transaction goes to the slot leader (TPU) the fastest, I need to send it to the validator connected to slot leader the fastest right?

Answer (score 1):

Many questions in one. I would recommend breaking them down to individual, focused questions.

Yes for every epoch, there is schedule that will select a slot leader for every slot (~ 400 - 800ms) on a predetermined basis.

For the next questions, you're using the word "guarantee" which is a strong word. Since leaders change fast, slot times vary widely, etc, there is simply no way you can guarantee to come in first. This is exacerbated by unpredictable network routes. You can, though, increase your chances to send your transactions to the right validator at the right time.

Yes, it's true that any single validator cannot be in both TVU and TPU mode at any given point in time.

And yes, the faster your connection to the slot leader, the higher your chances of getting through fast. However, at times of traffic peaks, there are several measures introduced with version 1.10.25 that might hinder your transaction from being processed immediately, and you might have to bid an increased fee during these times for specifics apps (i.e. programs).

Comment: I'm sorry for question dump, I should've known StackExchange would not take kindly to them. Will limit my response to one followup question: If leaders are predetermined, I know what each slot's leader at start of previous epoch (as per docs), so I can optimize order sending using that schedule right?

Comment: Another thing to note is that validators can forward transactions to other validators or decide to hold transactions if they know they will be a leader soon. Also validator nodes can choose to order transactions however they want in the block they are leader for, so short of running your own validator and being selected as leader for the block in question, there's no way to guarantee that you'll be first.

Comment: If slot leader reorders transactions, can other validators reject that? Or is leader's ordering absolute?'